# multilevel push menu jquery plugins not all browser supportable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multilevel push menu jquery plugins.
so i provided this plugins link here    [MultiLevelPushMenu](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html).

this plugins is not all browser supportable like...(1.R:  800x600 ,  1024x768 , 1280x1024  |     B:Internet Explorer 9  |   OS:window 7 |)

how can make this all browser supportable and  what is the issues in that plugins.
               please any one answer me...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the issues page of this plugin https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu/issues

I suggest you ask your question there for best results.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a jQuery implementation in JSFiddle, maybe it works.
See in action in : https://jsfiddle.net/b464Lgt1/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
      collapsed: false,
      menuWidth: '300px',
      mode: 'cover',
      fullCollapse: false,
      swipe: 'both',
      onMenuReady: function(){
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand', 'Devices');
      }
    });
});
```